# How to use strip() on to array slice without storing in temporary array

Tags: python

I have at data that looks like this:

```
Probes  FOO BAR
1452463_x_at    306.564     185.705
1439374_x_at    393.742     330.495
1426392_a_at    269.850     209.931
1433432_x_at    636.145     487.012
```

In the second column it contain white space after tab.

```
import sys
import csv
import pprint
with open('tmp.txt') as tsvfile:
   tabreader = csv.reader(tsvfile,delimiter="\t");
   for row in tabreader:
       #val = s.strip() for s in [row[1:3]]
       val = row[1:3]
       print val
```

Here is the code that prints this:

```
['FOO', 'BAR']
['306.564 ', '185.705']
['393.742 ', '330.495']
['269.850 ', '209.931']
['636.145 ', '487.012']
```

Now what I want to do is to strip the white space on the fly while iterating through the row,
without storing the values in temporary array. 
Especially with this line:

```
 #val = s.strip() for s in [row[1:3]]
```

But why it failed? What's the way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the syntax wrong.  You want a list-comprehension:

```
val = [s.strip() for s in row[1:3]]
```

Now, I'm not exactly sure what you want, but I *have* created a new list.  There's no clean<sup>1</sup> way around that.

<sup><sup>1</sup>You could use an explicit loop and strip the values while re-assigning them to the original list, but ... Yuck...</sup>

---

If you really want to, you can mutate the row in place this way:

```
row[:] = [s.strip() for s in row[1:3]]
```

But I'm not completely sure what advantage you'd get here.

Answer (score 1):

There's a concept of [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) in python. This is a lazy-evaluated version of list-comprehension that does not create a resulting list immediately. However, ordinary `print` does not cause the generator to evaluate, so you'll need to convert it to list before printing.

So, with your code it should look like (note *round brackets*)

```
for row in tabreader:
   val = (s.strip() for s in row[1:3])
   print list(val)
```

Using generator expression doesn't realy have any advantages over list comprehension in your example as you are going to print the result right away. It could be very handy if you need to do some additional processing on huge lists, reducing memory footprint due to the fact that generator expression does not allocate memory required to hold results.

In two words: list-comprehension works like `range` (allocates the list and fills it with data right away), generator expression works like `xrange` (generates next item on-demand)